# 3D Calculating the Z position of a point in a triangle

Tags: javascript, arrays, graphics, 3d, calculation

To create my three-dimensional engine, I used rasterization: dividing the triangles at their points.
However to carry out the rasterization I convert the points into the 2 dimensions. I then add the dot to a list that will render them later. To rearrange them, however, I need to know the Z position of the points.
So my question is: I have a triangle in 3 dimensions. I then convert it into the 2 dimensions. For each single point, how do I know the Z position, knowing its position of the 2 dimensions?
I tried a weird formula, which based on the distance from the points averaged the Z positions, but it's not working; Can you help me?

Comment: We need way more details than that. There is no such thing as "convert into 2d`. Or to be more accurate, there are an infinite number of ways to do that. So from what you said, we have no mean to know what those 2d are,

Comment: By converting it to 2d, as you say, are you simply picking up the (x,y) and discarding the z? If so, could you place the z coordinate for every triangle into a separate array, and retrieve it from there? For example (in pseudo-code): `var trg = [ [(1,2),(1,18),(55,6)], [...], [...], ...];` would store your reduced triangles, and `var zeds = [ [3,5,7], [...], [...], ... ];` would keep your removed z coordinates. The indices / indexes of both arrays would tell you which of the zeds belongs where. This assumes you won't be changing the ordering of coordinates within `trg`.

Comment: But, as chrslg mentioned, please add more details, because we could keep guessing, reaching no solution, and waste time by doing so.